# How to drill into objects and assert their type with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I am doing this a lot in my TypeScript project ([here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gO2AQwJYIgJwCrmgXigG8AoKKCAM0ogGNgAuKAUWrt0igB8oBnYTOgDm3KAgCuAWwBGWURIA2C0dLhwFEZAhIBfEiVCdWNWhwLEyUANoBrCCCb9BCIQF0m8JGgw48u-ZTiCPSoiFCovADy0gBWdMAAFAAeTEE2CHAA7ggAlExJ4bxQcLHxFuSYEMDimAhQhhBwlFAF+G1QAOQlcfQd-iSBwcChdci8vFjA0T2JKVBpGdl5UGMTmMBFBRHFpfTl4c0JAIQR0-HJOTn75MAAFphZYhCZLJgPmAkdGcAA+t3xHRylj0egGQRCYVWkwAqtCAJIAEWSqQQ6SyuSYUPWm0KfAEwn2qEODSaLSgR3aHScwkB13q90eGBezDecA+Xzgv2pLkBwP6gwhdQinhQ6CwyPmqMWGLJ2xF3iwZn2lWqtXJAEE3sgQAA6CKazDai5QABkJsKZ3oF354OGkPGk3lYo+cwW6OWWI2sqKTp8StI5CJUGOwsQop8FyuAfI9IeLyZr3en2+PyoJmAvPIIICtpGhQAQmoNFoADzYAB8ErdS3yuNU6k0dWjKpqdRJzValPrxYQfVBDSgcIQYHEwAACshDZJeErCNHUAATRz4lyWBRaITiZBCCA-RfL5xCSwANywRNQEAXAH4mN3G-0IEkwGzgCteCBglABXahQg1ok03iJhjHYPAo0sWhEH4cIFygQgOgARgAJgAZj6SxPUtAC2HoIFyE9X1xUA+gdXXFwtx3PC33-LCEmI4BSI3CiIB1eiqIIsMFQ+ejGPI7cWJ4xd2IddZaJ4sjN341icIYxdpPTYT-1hRE6Jk3jJJ3eT4j1BctNw-RyEgv9X3QEdGEHYdRwnKcZzwOC6UXAAaSxyAk5i9yXCg1LcqTBN0+jnKzAyDmDUMvGdVT0x1U9BEoC8F0uBzDgiQsGy0SLtJi89Lz04BEujGNwkshisriy97J40r4tylyoD0IKIKghtSLgIQElM0crgAei6qAFzgPg4EkaAF2kPhkGPAlbiwFidR1fwgA) is a playground):

```
type ContainerType = {
  effect: EffecType | string | number | null | boolean
}

type EffecType = {
  [key: string]: ContainerType
}

function isObject(x: unknown): x is object {
  return typeof x === 'object'
}

function assertObject(x: unknown): asserts x is object {
  if (!isObject(x)) {
    throw new Error('not_object')
  }
}

function assertUUID(x: unknown): asserts x is string {
  if (typeof x !== 'string') {
    throw new Error('not_string')
  }
}

function isContainer(x: unknown): x is ContainerType {
  return !Array.isArray(x) && isObject(x)
}

function assertContainer(x: unknown): asserts x is ContainerType {
  if (!isContainer(x)) {
    throw new Error('not_effect')
  }
}

function isBoolean<T>(x: unknown): x is boolean {
  return typeof x === 'boolean'
}

type InputParamsType = {
  id: string
  language_id: string
  verified?: boolean
}

export async function insert(effect: EffecType) {
  const id = '123'

  assertObject(effect)
  assertContainer(effect.language)
  assertObject(effect.language.effect)
  assertContainer(effect.language.effect.id)
  assertUUID(effect.language.effect.id.effect)

  const input: InputParamsType = {
    id,
    language_id: effect.language.effect.id.effect,
  }

  if (isContainer(effect.verified)) {
    if (isBoolean(effect.verified.effect)) {
      input.verified = effect.verified.effect
    }
  }

  console.log(input) // do some db saving here...
}
```

Notice how I am doing 2 annoying things:

1. assertions slowly down the branch of the tree to get to language id (effect.x.effect.x...). At least it's flat and not nested.
2. then conditional checks slowly down the tree in a nested fashion to get to the verified prop.
3. I have 20 other properties I need to do this for, just for this model.

How can I do something more like this with TypeScript?

```
assertUUID(effect, 'language.effect.id.effect')

const input: InputParamsType = {
  id,
  language_id: effect.language.effect.id.effect,
};

if (isBoolean(effect, 'verified.effect')) {
  input.verified = effect.verified.effect;
}
```

In that way, there is only minimal assertions and nesting required to make it work. Is it possible somehow? Doesn't have to be that exact API if there is an alternative way to somehow get rid of all these initial declarations and nestings from the first snippet.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253655/discussion-on-question-by-lance-how-to-drill-into-objects-and-assert-their-type); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to have a function you passed a concrete example object into, allowing TypeScript to work with simpler types (avoiding recursion and such that a path-based approach would need). It does have the issue of being a bit verbose, though.

Here's an example that doesn't attempt to handle union types:

```typescript
const effect: any = {/*...whatever...*/};

effect;
// ^? −−− const effect: any

assertMatch(effect, { object: { effect: { id: { effect: "" } } } }, "invalid_object_id");
assertMatch(effect, { object: { effect: { type: { effect: "" } } } }, "invalid_object_type");
// Or alternatively:
// assertMatch(effect, { object: { effect: { id: { effect: "" }, type: { effect: "" } } } }, "invalid_object_id_or_type");

effect;
// ^? −−− const effect: { object: { effect: { id: { effect: string } } } } & { object: { effect: { type: { effect: string } } } };

const id = "123";

const input = {
    id,
    object_id: effect.object.effect.id.effect,
    object_type: effect.object.effect.type.effect,
};

// Marginally improved `typeof`
function getType(x: any) {
    const rawType = typeof x;
    if (rawType === "object" && !x) {
        return "null";
    }
    return rawType;
}

export function assertMatch<TargetType>(
    x: any,
    example: TargetType,
    message: string = "invalid value"
): asserts x is TargetType {
    // >>> Incomplete and off-the-cuff, not meant to be an all-singing, all-dancing
    // implementation, just a sketch <<<
    const typex = getType(x);
    if (typex !== getType(example)) {
        throw new Error(message);
    }
    if (typex === "object") {
        for (const name in example) {
            assertMatch(x[name], example[name], message);
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBApgMwXYUBcMCGYCeMC8MA3gFAzkwD0lMAKgBZwRxYBOLAVgK7QyPswAlmBjBMzGDhBdRAG0HAA1jABKXMABoYEEENgB3QbNlZUXTMZxkK1GAFtMUYPQB0MNAFoAlDABCXWChGGAADbBwQmCgcAAcWcCjggBMUWUxWR0EEmPYANzgwKAg6WLgAZWBWQRioa3JbBFYQOyEwZFYqsABzRJZouJhG5t6YXIsuOBc6mBAAIw4UdGJpingkRYxSVe2KQSTNlZ3txGRUDAAiPbXTqHONQ52AX3uj7f64A9fXk42YS6Tros7g9ts8QWDVmDHgBuEgkH6oWG2AB6AH44eJmKwoABZRzOAAUCKgWiIM3mvzJxM2Qn2xEBZz+5xgjxZbOef2EY3kSQA+nMFqheXtzl5YZi4Ni8U56ET1qhSeTBUsqfKVVFSjTqUz2eytJcwNy9vyKUL3qKkTQAPKsLCyKCSsCZfKyHBoEi2CVS-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-4anE75tsJ8Eftm0EwAS7z9ZhSGDW+cDyVVXi4a8QRNPoMBgHAa0AKIdOmBKaTZOlwCNFBUaN42lP1iFlihS1HAg6ZjT1Tqaa0ckKQFx1uV8WA2ZKvEyh+ADaL1wAAuloc0fUpIMKeDWgHdpT4nU8lEkFRQA)

That involves creating and disposing the example objects, but short-lived small objects are constantly created and disposed in JavaScript/TypeScript code and JavaScript engines are very good at it.

That can probably be expanded to handle unions, if you need to handle them, by passing on multiple example objects. Something along these lines:

```typescript
const effect: any = {/*...*/};

effect;
// ^?

assertMatchesAny(
    effect,
    [
        { object: { effect: { id: { effect: 0 } } } },  // a number...
        { object: { effect: { id: { effect: "" } } } }, // ...or a string
    ],
    "invalid_object_id"
);
assertMatchesAny(effect, [{ object: { effect: { type: { effect: "" } } } }], "invalid_object_type");
// Or alternatively:
// assertMatch(effect, { object: { effect: { id: { effect: "" }, type: { effect: "" } } } }, "invalid_object_id_or_type");

effect;
// ^?

const id = "123";

const input = {
    id,
    object_id: effect.object.effect.id.effect,
    object_type: effect.object.effect.type.effect,
};

// Marginally improved `typeof`
function getType(x: any) {
    const rawType = typeof x;
    if (rawType === "object" && !x) {
        return "null";
    }
    return rawType;
}

export function matchesAny<TargetType>(
    x: any,
    examples: TargetType[],
): x is TargetType {
    for (const example of examples) {
        // >>> Incomplete and off-the-cuff, not meant to be an all-singing, all-dancing
        // implementation, just a sketch <<<
        let matches = true;
        const typex = getType(x);
        if (typex !== getType(example)) {
            matches = false;
        } else if (typex === "object") {
            for (const name in example) {
                matches = matchesAny(x[name], [example[name]]);
                if (!matches) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (matches) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

export function assertMatchesAny<TargetType>(
    x: any,
    examples: TargetType[],
    message: string = "invalid value"
): asserts x is TargetType {
    if (!matchesAny(x, examples)) {
        throw new Error(message);
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-mpvlWv7Ce17Z2M1CO97nb0kWwAeSNFig0rAmXyshwaBLIogWP9TnoocTWkjedjMdZewTNwuKa08Y5GuT2tTWlt2adUfzOcNBdKRdh8MTSJoaLhoEgsCuhHOAEYAEwAZnOG-3vGEMQCBGWqz21oVi3d7IpBt7Lm-ez-LtpkXN1x2-EDAJuFx3kgxZ7hhOFbDxVgumECx6yEOwchAfIARCd4QAQEISAQdRUCyEQujgKBaFKEkAA8MHCHwtgoW9YAyfRaIGQgCIQGB6NhF9+JJTjuJYfBJL+ECtQAMlkmAAEJ6JYkF2CgLhWBEc5xWMa9pkeaZ1M0kQxNKWFDPheiYkNWBSLAciEgcdsiVwAAeWh0iomjSgAPjJVZGKwXA3zgejMCw2QmAwTyUOo8TqStL0MHooRili7zxOfCgEENGASXY+Bwsi+J+LCiKYiiiBVNeWxfPqmAAEkHOaSrqJYbAAUIhAPCCOAPGALgkC0MAQFgOw4GwQJdClYKsGMDwIGEVDui0dCPCSbBgGWkFbEEEqJsKTJwC0bheFFCBFGo5wYDcu6QSi8aAyYJ9TQmISjkK95UsITK6JUj6dkEETvqUqS-riUNirarwaq+chnIJYpCAQCxmEB0F4FkCRgfy0HJOPGS4fh3KjQK8BeBrCbWiKiqouJ+GKERwMn2Z1yQ3o6kqbgDNqXKkquYinmLWLRntlxklFLZ6rsrFnZZnYTBFAxsXDNV8EQQl6WGdeYytKiVh3o1yEjOokzBjRuALLhMKbOxQYyKgCisBbP08RcoN3Iy+K-ICiggvCULoaqmKvJ9uJErfCaW0wKiMGgM0nznCwrntCZPS8JjXexYpUsEdKw58gZWPICWpeez2Oa0fm2uqnWKCCJp9DFOBm4AUQ6Q0SWjiBY7gUWKEMx4gA)

Comment: Nice, this would work too I think! Thank you. I don't _think_ I'll need unions right this second, but if it's on the top of your mind how it can be done, that would be great if you could add it, I don't at first see how to follow your suggestion at the end to completion.

Comment: @Lance - I've added the first approach that comes to mind.

Comment: Creating many objects I'm not concerned with either, this got me wondering if maybe you could use a string path to construct a comparator object, and then do the comparison like you are doing, but I can't find a way to make that work either. Maybe your approach is best so far.

Comment: @Lance - Which is really too bad, because jcalz's approach is so much more *elegant*. :-) But so far at least, seems the compiler can't handle it.

Comment: Yep, would have been cool, but now I like your approach a lot, it's [pretty clean too](https://gist.github.com/lancejpollard/781e799356ec43a00bd624ddfa28ad83)!

Answer (score 2):

This approach uses dotted path strings, as suggested in the question.  First let's make a `NestedRecord<K, V>` utility type which takes a dotted path string `K` and a value `V` and produces an object type with the appropriate shape:

```
type NestedRecord<K extends string, V> =
  K extends `${infer K0}.${infer KR}` ?
  { [P in K0]: NestedRecord<KR, V> } :
  { [P in K]: V };
```

That's a recursively-defined [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) that parses `K` into the part `K0` before the first dot and the part `KR` after it, and produces an object with key `K0` and value `NestedRecord<KR, V>`. If `K` has no dot then we're at the last path segment and we just need the equivalent of `Record<K, V>`.

Now let's make a `Merge<T, U>` utility type that deeply merges a type `T` with a type `U`, assuming that there's no conflict between them.  In a perfect world this could just be the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) `T & U`, but that doesn't seem to play nicely with [index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures).  This seems to work:

```
type Merge<T, U> = Extract<
  T extends object ? U extends object ? { [K in keyof (T & U)]:
    K extends keyof T ? K extends keyof U ?
    Merge<T[K], U[K]> : T[K] :
    K extends keyof U ? U[K] : never } : U : T & U,
  T
>
```

Essentially we are walking down through `T` and `U` and recursively merging them until we hit non-objects, and then returning either just the non-object (so that `string & {a:{b:{c:⋯}}}` is just `string` for simplicity) or the intersection for both non-objects.  And one big use of [the `Extract` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) to convince the compiler that `Merge<T, U>` is always assignable to `T`.

---

Armed with those we can make our functions.  Let's write a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) [custom type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) that verifies that the property of the input `x` at nested path `path` has the type guarded by an input type guard function `guard`:

```
function guardPath<T, K extends string, V>(
  x: T, path: K, guard: (x: any) => x is V
): x is Merge<T, NestedRecord<K, V>> {
  for (const k of path.split(".")) {
    if (x == null) return false; // can't index into this
    x = (x as any)[k];
  }
  return guard(x);
}
```

This says that the input is of type `T` and the output, if true, is `Merge<T, NestedRecord<K, V>>` where `K` is the type of `path` and `V` is the type guarded by `guard`.  The implementation just splits `path` at dots and iterates indexing down until it either hits something it can't index into or can apply the guard to the final value.

You also wanted an [assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) so we can use `guardPath` to implement that... it's quite similar:

```
function assertPath<T, K extends string, V>(
  x: T, path: K, guard: (x: any) => x is V, vname: string = "valid value"
): asserts x is Merge<T, NestedRecord<K, V>> {
  if (!guardPath(x, path, guard))
    throw new Error("no " + vname + " found at path " + path)
};
```

The only difference is asking for a name for the type of `V` so that the error message is meaningful.

---

Okay, let's try it out!  Here are some basic type guard functions:

```
const isString = (x: any): x is string => typeof x === "string";
const isBoolean = (x: any): x is boolean => typeof x === "boolean";
const isNumber = (x: any): x is number => typeof x === "number";
```

And given your `ContainerType`, `EffecType` (*sic*), and `InputParamsType`, here's a possible implementation of `insert()`:

```
function insert(effect: EffecType) {
  const id = '123'

  assertPath(effect, "language.effect.id.effect", isString, "string");
  assertPath(effect, "language.effect.otherProp.effect", isNumber, "number");
  const input: InputParamsType = {
    id,
    language_id: effect.language.effect.id.effect,
  }
  if (guardPath(effect, "verified.effect", isBoolean)) {
    input.verified = effect.verified.effect
  }
  console.log(input) // do some db saving here...
}
```

Inside the function at the point we write `input.verified =`, you can inspect `effect` to see its type is

```
/* (parameter) effect: {
  [x: string]: ContainerType;
  language: {
      effect: {
        [x: string]: ContainerType;
        id: {
            effect: string;
        };
        otherProp: {
            effect: number;
        };
    };
};
verified: {
    effect: boolean;
}; } */
```

which is the result of three `Merge`s.  And when you call it, it behaves as expected:

```
insert({
  language: {
    effect: {
      id: { effect: "abcde" },
      otherProp: { effect: 123 }
    }
  },
  verified: { effect: true }
});
/* {
  "id": "123",
  "language_id": "abcde",
  "verified": true
}  */

try {
  insert({
    language: { effect: "oopsie" }
  });
  //  RUNTIME ERROR! no string found at path language.effect.id.effect 
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAclAziKATASlAxgewE6oA8A0jFAB4oB2qiMyeAllQOYA0MAagHwwC8wGDFIVqtGAAMAJAG9mAMyh5hABgC+AOlkKlw9GokwA-IJgyYAbQAKMZqoC6ALnhIUGbPiLF0HHjDUwjqbm1rZUwk5c-gDcwKCQsACySixQhAAqHACqvHwwAKKUeACGWCCEpulklFA0dDgARgBW2CDGMFnVYvXNre0hpHYA1lBgOPIwABRVAGQdAJROpkIiNXUwI2MTVUbCXbXim+MdxsswyXipGRbE9tk39rzO6Q+BZ6vdG6PHnbtZr84qFAAG66ALOTrPGBzLJsSrAbhxYDyACuVDKjBw4RYKOKBCsxRAAAsMhwPgc6AxmOwuNxJqZyM8OBBCUTnMQODi8ahnJNGTBilQwPN+LxyLY6JxgPNnOLGHQLldMi5kGhMLgCCRfNxeDJTPJ8FNcFRkBsYMcWcSNIgIAAbRggSYAIg0TvmIr1QiEjAmfP4eSoKNttpFeCgIBReHC8mKtsQUGiMAA9EmYFhBQByNrMVAUMIgHAwYnys7ivJ+4p0QXCixDeyxIRqUxhiNRmBcgh8+axJuo9EgTHhSvxvAgAnE0l7UQU+ggJisbX0oT85WWtnCTm4gi8-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-btN8xb63er6SG8-TxOvT6H2oLLZTy-KpneYK7pmGcfPJgAVFMLKG+GSginzziel6Fj8rpC0FUVQKrQknNCI7qQZ2cZvp9HZu11nOcs3nS0FyVxeV3XCMVx33dkPTT3UiXPeCe3dfi0SkvS13Pd19Xqt4IP3fD4vg9L16-vvWgU8z33-WOT5K89jAcdJmczD6xo6+B3e9uX2gwcgKYTZIkIIneQ7OAsJMZ-7SKKYwKghZEA4CYqgBo9BijAikuPMMGhYF-WRGiQG0YzIEx3mNBqCRYY425n+H24MOAZhRCOe+NMg58wzEzRAEllL8WwTzVkqD8EwAzI0Fo1MXZkPphQiU1DqS0K5vQ4kjCibMNYa0EhI177cOZjQ0w9sxHsPphoSR9sCxZAgNAPAuVKxQEmOrJ+cRmAg0mJnMuV4a5emrpnM2j0zC93Bs4J0xQGhYFzDRNQ7szZjwnjgCAGd7GtGcGjdGHsvRNkbO7W+50Ko7znB+daah1ZJgTpnJ0z4nSOOCYzUwJMbrW1thk+8zjXGfndg+JQAc0CFLiVAASQhj5xDnGACxRi-wmLOGY-x1cnRmQgIgD67jH7qyEH-QAvBuAFKdmA6AshwHSFtRI+QCjoHQAAeXQPBIigCWasRwOxAUbRuJmJIa7emMA6nphAFgIkUwoBYLTAFN+toP4E30UAA)

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, however after adding a couple of assertions, the compiler adds an index signature, and I can pass any string :/.

[playground](https://tsplay.dev/w6G10N)

Comment: And sadly: https://shorturl.at/exTW2 (line 89). The compiler just can't seem to handle this. ‍♀️ indeed.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/gL0skuV

Comment: @TJCrowder shorturl.at doesn't bring me anywhere useful.  I mean, I get redirected to the main page; I have no problem with tsplay.dev, could you link there?

Comment: @Lance I unfortunately can't use images in my IDE. Care to provide a link or edit?

Comment: @wonderflame the type already had an index signature; it's an `EffecType`. If that's a problem then the input type should probably be made something like `{}` instead of `EffecType` maybe as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/WP89EW).

Comment:  So far the comments here are largely of the form "I have a problem with this answer and the evidence is this" *points to a picture of a cow driving a sports car*.  I would love to investigate but I don't know how to.

Comment: @jcalz - Well that's weird, I get the same result from that link. Here: https://tsplay.dev/w8YLPN

Comment: (Just tried shorturl.at again, and it failed again. But wonderflame seems to be able to make it work. Strange.)

Comment: Okay well at least now I can look at it... might be a while before I can get to a real computer though

Comment: At first glance, [something seriously bad is happening](https://tsplay.dev/Nl8eBN).  The types work, but the assertion function fails to apply properly.  No idea how to resolve it with the current architecture.  Maybe there's a relevant bug in the TS github repo but I don't know.

Comment: I mean [what more does it want from me?](https://tsplay.dev/wR7XnN) The types are correct to the best of my ability to make them.  Oh wellz.

Comment: I filed [ms/TS#54246](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/54246).  Looks like a regression happened at some point after TS4.9 where my suggestion would have worked without problem (and I would have gotten those yummy points instead of banging my head against it for nuffin)